# regenerate-certs required everytime the machine IP change

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-machine

I'm using docker-machine on AWS and everytime I reboot the machine (and its IP changes) I need to regenerate the certificates because of this message :

> Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the
>   certs: There was an error validating certificates for host
>   "54.154.223.120:2376": x509: certificate is valid for 54.171.150.8,
>   not 54.154.223.120

Is there a way to avoid doing that ? (maybe a way to generate the certificates for any IP ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid that using [Elastic IPs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html).
It is basically a reserved NIC attached to your instance so it can survive reboots. You can even re-allocate to another instance.
Hope it helps

Comment: Please avoid linking to external content only. Describe your answer here and - if necessary - link to external ressources for reference.